# Prolog recursively applying a function to a list

Tags: prolog

I have a list of lists and I want to remove duplicates from all of them.

I already have the code for removing duplicates from a list.

The only thing I need to do is to apply this to the whole list and return it via the second argument.

This is what I tried.

```
rem_list_dup([], _).
rem_list_dup([H | T], Final) :-
    remove_duplicates(H, List), /* This already works. Removes all duplicates from list H. List is the resulting list */
    rem_list_dup(T, [List | Final]).
```

EDIT:

Example Input:

`[[a, b, a], [b, b, c], [c, c, c]]`

Output:

`[[a, b], [b,c], [c]]`

The order does not matter.

Comment: The first argument is a list ```[H | T]``` and ```H``` is its head.

Comment: Updated with examples

Comment: After tracing it, I noticed the base case is utterly wrong. But I have no idea what to write instead. This is what I see hard in Prolog compared to other languages. The recursion is all good, but then it needs to actually pattern match to a base case. I would normally do ```rem_list_dup([], []).``` because I want ```Final``` to be ```[]``` in the end, but then it doesn't pattern match anymore. Yikes.

Comment: You just deleted [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833674/prolog-should-this-happen). Please note that people will refrain from answering your questions, if you delete your question. That is like tearing away the paper under a writing hand.

Comment: I deleted it because it was marked as a bad question due to lacking clarity. I'm new here, so I assumed that questions that are marked like that disappear from the question list. I'm sorry.

Comment: @false I figured out how to undelete it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you understand basics of using recursion and a base case down and know how to use a tracer, you should be able to quickly understand the few changes here without needing a walk thru of the why.

```
remove_duplicates(List,Set) :-
    list_to_set(List,Set).

rem_list_dup([],[]).
rem_list_dup([H0|T0],[H|T]) :-
    remove_duplicates(H0,H),
    rem_list_dup(T0,T).

:- begin_tests(rem_list_dup).

rem_list_dup_test_case_generator([[a, b, a], [b, b, c], [c, c, c]],[[a, b], [b,c], [c]]).

test(1,[forall(rem_list_dup_test_case_generator(List0,List))]) :-
    rem_list_dup(List0,List).

% Based on comment by @false
test(2,[forall(rem_list_dup_test_case_generator(List0,List))]) :-
    maplist(list_to_set,List0,List).

:- end_tests(rem_list_dup).
```

Example run using SWI-Prolog

```
?- consult("C:/Users/Groot/Documents/Projects/Prolog/SO_question_182.pl").
true.

?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: rem_list_dup .. done
% All 2 tests passed
true.
```

Comment: It works exactly as I expected. Thank you and good job for figuring it out!

Comment: @EricSpataru No problem. Just years of writing recursive predicates.

Comment: `rem_list_dup(Ts, Us) :- maplist(remove_duplicates, Ts, Us).`

Comment: @false When you see the question about `yfy` remember that it is April 1, so don't ruin it.

Comment: Bien entendu ! However, I do remember such a question meant seriously. I will try to show it on April 2nd.

Comment: @false It seems that SWI-Prolog checks for `yfy`, e.g. `ERROR:    op/3: Domain error: `operator_specifier' expected, found `yfy'`  If you can think of a question I will post it.

Comment: Where is this `yfy` question. In any case, please search for `yfy` in comp.lang.prolog

Comment: See 8.14.3.3 i: Op_specifier is not a valid operator specifier
  - domain_error(operator_specifier,
    Op_specifier).

Comment: @false Thanks. Still would like to know where in the SWI-Prolog source code it is checking for op `yfy`. I would ask at the forum, but as we know, doing the work in finding the answer is of more value than getting the answer.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Certainly, there is no check for `yfy` but just for the  valid op-specifiers